# How do utilize JSON.Net from Cake build script?

Tags: c#, json.net, cakebuild

I would like to serialize and deserialize json using json.net in a Cake build script, but stuck at how to reference it.

Comment: Can you add an [mcve]? Or at least where/how you normally reference stuff

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to reference Newtonsoft JSON.Net is through the [#addin](http://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/preprocessor-directives) directive.  Example, usage:

`#addin packageid`

As it's not a "native" Cake addin you will need to add a using to namespaces or use fully qualified names of the types you want to use.  For example, put using at top of build script:

`using Newtonsoft.Json;`

or use fully qualified type names:

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...)`

Beyond this it's just "regular" C#

A complete example below:

```
#addin "nuget:https://www.nuget.org/api/v2?package=Newtonsoft.Json"
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MissingPerson
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

var john = new MissingPerson {
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe"
};


// Serialize and output MissingPerson as json
Information(
    "MissingPerson as json: {0}",
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(john, Formatting.Indented)
    );

/*
 * This will output
 * MissingPerson as json: {
 *   "FirstName": "John",
 *   "LastName": "Doe"
 * }
 */


var jsonMissingPerson = "{\"FirstName\": \"Jane\",\"LastName\": \"Doe\"}";

// Deserialize json string to object
var jane = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MissingPerson>(jsonMissingPerson);
Information(
    "Missing Person from json:\r\n\tFirstName: {0}\r\n\tLastName: {1}",
    jane.FirstName,
    jane.LastName
    );

/*
 * This will output
 * Missing Person from json:
 *        FirstName: Jane
 *        LastName: Doe
 */
```

The above sample also specifies which NuGet feed to fetch packages, which is a very powerful part of the [#addin](http://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/preprocessor-directives) directive. This means you could fetch assemblies from i.e. pre-release or private feeds.

Comment: Worked like a charm, this was exactly what i was looking for!
Thanks Mattias!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution might also be to use the [Cake.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cake.Json/) Addin.  It is documented [here](http://cakebuild.net/dsl/json).  It provides alias methods for the standard functionality, such as:

- Serialize
- Deserialize

It can be included within your Cake Script by simply adding:

`#addin "Cake.Json"`